# Matching strings in PhP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

The var $username needs to check for a match. How can I do this?

Progress:

```
if (isset($_GET["username"]) && !empty($_GET["username"])) 
{
    $username = $_GET['username'];

    $usercheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE user_login=".$username."",$con);
    closeCursor($usercheck);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

1) Escape the variable to prevent SQL injection using [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string).
2) Use quotes around the variable in where clause, because it is a string.
3) Check whether more than 0 rows were returned or not using [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/mysql_num_rows).

```
 $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username']);
 $usercheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE user_login='".$username."'",$con);

 if(mysql_num_rows($usercheck)>0)
      echo 'USER FOUND';
 else
      echo 'NOT FOUND';
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey I recommend using sprintf for security reasons.

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user='%s' AND password='%s'",
    mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username']),
    mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['password']);

// Perform Query
$result = mysql_query($query);

// Check result
// This shows the actual query sent to MySQL, and the error. Useful for debugging.
if (!$result) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
    die($message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[mysql_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) would tell you whether any users matched the provided username. You should also use `mysql_real_escape_string` to ensure that your username value is safely escaped for use in the query.  Also -- be sure your strings are quotes (using single-quotes) inside the mysql query.

Something like this should get you pointed in the right direction:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username'], $con);

$usercheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE user_login='".$username."'",$con);
if( mysql_num_rows($usercheck) <= 0 ) {
   // error: no such user was found
} else {
   // found one or more matching users
}
```